# RSpec include fails to find object

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

First, I am new to using RSpec and relatively new to Rails so I am still figuring out a lot of how this technologies work compared to my past language experience.

The problem, RSpec is failing a test and I don't see what it is that I am missing.

The test is testing the GET index of a controller.

The test:

```
it "populates an array of profiles" do
  profile = create(:profile)
  get :index
  expect(:profiles).to include(profile)
end
```

The result:

```
 1) ProfilesController GET #index populates an array of profiles
 Failure/Error: expect(:profiles).to include(profile)

   expected :profiles to include #<Profile id: 3, user_id: 2, name: "Kasandra Goldner", about: nil, country_code: nil, state_code: nil...15", avatar_file_name: nil, avatar_content_type: nil, avatar_file_size: nil, avatar_updated_at: nil>, but it does not respond to `include?`
   Diff:
   @@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
   -[#<Profile id: 3, user_id: 2, name: "Kasandra Goldner", about: nil, country_code: nil, state_code: nil, city: nil, created_at: "2017-02-27 03:42:15", updated_at: "2017-02-27 03:42:15", avatar_file_name: nil, avatar_content_type: nil, avatar_file_size: nil, avatar_updated_at: nil>]
   +:profiles

 # ./spec/controllers/profiles_controller_spec.rb:15:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try wrapping `:profiles` in assigns to get instance var which is set in the controller:

```
expect(assigns(:profiles)).to include(profile)
```

Comment: Thanks Kris that did it!